# Convert PHP echoed date to client local time

Tags: php, javascript, date, localtime

This is my first post. I have a problem that i can't seem to resolve. Here it goes:

I have a PHP script that prints the date of an event to the page:

```
$event_datetime = date("g:i A (m/d/y)", strtotime($row['event_time']));
echo $event_datetime
```

I want to use Javascript to convert that $event_datetime into client local timezone preferably or local client computer time.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: How can that be possible when the date/time string does not include any timezone information whatsoever? Can you tell me what time it is where you live if I tell you that it is 10 am somewhere in the world?

Comment: Basically the date is just printed out from the database in UTC. My main focus here is to convert a printed or return date from PHP into JS, but somehow getting to show in current time, kind of $returned_date - $localclienttime = ?? Kind of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use php to convert all dates into a timezone with:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

For example:

```
$time = time();
$date = date(DATE_RFC822, $time);
echo $date . PHP_EOL;

date_default_timezone_set("Australia/Perth");
$date = date(DATE_RFC822, $time);
echo $date. PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
Mon, 19 Aug 13 18:49:40 +0000
Tue, 20 Aug 13 02:49:40 +0800
```

You would just need to get the clients timezone from somewhere (a preference saved in the database or getting it via javascript for example).

See [Getting the client's timezone in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript) for using javascript

Comment: I tried both of these approach but to no avail to what my client needs. Maybe i'm doing the wrong question. Basically, i need to take a date and time, (time being more important) from a mySQL database, and somehow convert that time so the user seeing this admin panel can see events that happened a minute ago, in this format (00:00). So if the event ended at 5:30 in PST, he sees it on his panel at 7:30 EST. Does that makes sense ? Thanks though

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you pull the date out of the database, set the timezone to EST and create a date (after the change of timezone) and then echo it out, the time will be 7:30EST as you say.

Comment: Did not see this before posting my own answer, but you were right from the beggining, i'm marking this as the correct answer, even when i got it a slightly different way, Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

Instead of echoing a date to javascript, just echo the timestamp and use javascripts date object.

```
var date = new Date(<?php echo strtotime($row['event_time']) * 1000); ?>);
```

You can now use javascripts date object to print out the time however you want.
Like this:

```
date.toLocaleDateString();
//The default output will be the users' timezone (the client where the javascript is being executed), but can be configured with the options argument
```

See:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

For more on the javascript date object

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer to what i was looking for, but i thank you guys for taking the time to help. Your solution was great but not what i needed. Ok, here is how i got it:

Keeping in mind that $row['event_time'] is a datetime value saved on the database on UTC timezone.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $s_date = new DateTime($row['event_time'],new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
    $s_date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
    $start_event_time = $s_date->format('g:i:s A (m/d/y)');
    echo $start_event_time;
}
```

You can create an additional script that gets the current user timezone and change **America/New_York** to make it more dynamic.

Hope it helps someone with my same issue.